# Javascript keyboard navigation commands

Tags: javascript

Okay I found the following code via this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568379/how-to-change-page-with-javascript-for-keyboard-navigation) what I'm trying to achieve is when a user presses `shift + H`  that the user is taken to the site homepage using javascript.

I found this code;

```
function checkKeycode(e)
{
  var keycode;

  if (window.event)
    keycode = window.event.keyCode;
  else
    if (e) keycode = e.which;

  switch (keycode)
  {
    case 37:  // left arrow
      document.location = "page1.htm";
    break;

    case 39:  // right arrow
      document.location = "page3.htm";
    break;
  }
}
```

but wasn't sure if it was relevant to what I was trying to achieve.

Thankyou in advance for any help.

Comment: Sure, this is code that handles a key event. You can use that as a starting point for what you want to do. I recommend to read about `keycode` and key event objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `event.shiftKey`. Below I have posted links to an example hosted on my website.

[Demonstration](http://jackgiffin.com/beta/SHIFT_key_test.html)
[Source code (file extension changed to .txt)](http://jackgiffin.com/beta/SHIFT_key_test.txt)

Compatibility: Tested in IE7, and should work in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding one more case for 72, use window.location=homepageurl.